# ui-bootstrap accordion header trigger

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to get ui-bootstrap accordion to only trigger (expand) on a div within the accordion-header. I've tried setting the is-open to false but no luck. The idea is that I simply want all kinds of ng-click's on the accordion-header but only one that will expand it.

```
<accordion-group class="panel-default">
      <accordion-heading>

        // ****** I'd like this to be one of the things that expands the accordion
        <span class="editable">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download" ></span>&nbsp;
          {{product.name}}&nbsp;
        </span>

        // ****** but not this..
        <span class="editable">
           <span is-open="false" ng-click="editProduct(item)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
        </span>

        <span class="pull-right" >

          <span class="badge access_group" ng-click="fetchMembers(product)" ng-show="product.members_count > 0">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
            </span> 
            {{product.members_count}}
          </span>&nbsp;

          // ****** but this should as well...
          <span class="badge access_group editable" ng-click="fetchServiceProducts(product)" ng-show="product.children_products_count > 0">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download">
            </span> 
            {{product.children_products_count}}
          </span>
        </span>

      </accordion-heading>
      {{product.description}}
      <accordion>
        <div ng-repeat="product in product.products" ng-include="'product_renderer.html'"></div>
      </accordion>
    </accordion-group>
```

If there is something I'm missing please let me know.